# How do you add a nodequeue to an existing view on the front page?

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I'm confused on how to get a nodequeue to appear on the front page?

I took over an existing Drupal website with Views and [Nodequeue](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodequeue) installed.

- I created the nodequeue I want to add to the front page view as well as the nodes to include in the queue.
- I duplicated the "relationship" and "sort"/ "filter" settings from the views that are already on the homepage.
- This nodequeue I created looks fine when I preview it..

How do I actually assign the nodequeue to display on the front page like the others? I can't figure it out for the life of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OPTION 1**

Edit your Nodequeue view and click on +Add button and select `Attachment`.

Now go to your front page view and in the FOOTER add `Global: View area` and select your attachment.

**OPTION 2**

In blocks, place the Nodequeue view block on a region and configure the block, for **Visivility Settings** select `only listed pages` and put `<front>`